# how to add parentheses before a negative number in python

Tags: python

I have built a project that calculates the quadratic equations and finds the solution. I have given an input to enter the value of `a`,`b` and `c`. When I enter the values then the full quadratic equation appears. For example I enter `a:2`,`b:3`,`c:4`, it appears `2x2+3x+4`. Now the problem is with the negative numbers. If I give `b` a value of `-3` and `c` a value of `-4`, the quadratic equation appears like this:`2x2+-3x+-4`. Now I want it to appear in this form:
`2x2+(-3)x+(-4)`. Can anyone help?

This is my code:

```
a=int(input("Enter the value of a:"))
b=int(input("Enter the value of b:"))
c=int(input("Enter the value of c:"))
d = b**2-(4*a*c)
if b>0 and c>0:
    print("The quadratic equation is : " + str(a) + "x2+" + str(b) + "x+" + str(c))
elif b<0 and c<0:
    print("The quadratic equation is : " + str.format(a) + "x2+" + str(b) + "x+" + str(c))
```

Comment: If you use formatted string, u need a string. You cant write str.format(var). This syntax is totally wrong. You must have a string, and inside the string u can place { } to insert something. For example, print("My name is {}".format("riccardo")) prints "My name is riccardo". It can be used also with number. Inside the brackets you can write par1:par2.xf, with par1 is index of element that u write in ( ), par2 is space researved for the string, and x is precision. If u write: a = 3.14656 b = 4.5435 print("a={0:4.2f}, b={1:4.2f}".format(a, b) it prints "a = 3.14, b = 4.54"

Answer (score 2):

You can define function which will add parentheses if number is negative and use it instead of `str()`:

```
def fmt_num(x):
    return str(x) if x >= 0 else "({})".format(x)

...

print("The quadratic equation is : " + fmt_num(a) + "x2+" + fmt_num(b) + "x+" + fmt_num(c))
```

Answer (score 2):

That's an alternative if you want it even more readable:

```
def beauty(coeff, i):

    if(coeff == 0): return ''

    if(i == 2):

        if(coeff ==  1): return  "x\u00B2"
        if(coeff == -1): return "-x\u00B2"
        return f"{coeff}x\u00B2"

    if(i == 1):

        if(coeff ==  1): return "+x"
        if(coeff == -1): return "-x"
        if(coeff  >  0): return f"+{coeff}x"
        return f"{coeff}x"

    if(i == 0):

        if(coeff >  0): return f"+{coeff}"
        return f"{coeff}"


def PrintQuadratic():

    a = int(input('a: '))
    b = int(input('b: '))
    c = int(input('c: '))

    print(f"{beauty(a,2)}{beauty(b,1)}{beauty(c,0)}")
```

---

```
PrintQuadratic()
a: 7
b: 9
c: 13
→ 7x²+9x+13

PrintQuadratic()
a: -1
b:  1
c:  0
→ -x²+x

PrintQuadratic()
a: 4
b: -2
c: 1
→ 4x²-2x+1
```

It's a little bit longer, but produces nice prints.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Python's string formatting in a better way, using a function that maps an integer `n` to `str(n)` if it's positive, or to `(-str(n))` if it's negative:

```
def f(n):
    return str(n) if n >= 0 else '(%d)' % n

print("The quadratic equation is : {0}x2+{1}x+{2}".format(f(a), f(b), f(c)))
```

An even better format I should suggest is to actually place the sign of the number instead of a static `+` between the operands, and avoid parenthesis:

```
def f(n):
    return ('+' if n >= 0 else '-') + '%d' % abs(n)

eq_f = '{0}x2{1}x{2}'

print("The quadratic equation is : " + eq_f.format(f(a), f(b), f(c)))
```

Output (example):

```
Enter the value of a:-1
Enter the value of b:5
Enter the value of c:-4
The quadratic equation is : -1x2+5x-4
```

Answer (score 0):

just add () for each var and chnge + to - in the second test because + with - = -

```
a=int(input("Enter the value of a:"))
b=int(input("Enter the value of b:"))
c=int(input("Enter the value of c:"))
d = (b)**2-(4*(a)*(c))
if b>0 and c>0:
    print("The quadratic equation is : " + str(a) + "x2+" + str(b) + "x+" + str(c))
elif b<0 and c<0:
    print("The quadratic equation is : " + str.format(a) + "x2" + str(b) + "x" + str(c))
```

Comment: It changes nothing.